# connect to windows share automatically and rsync

Tags: ssh, samba, rsync

I have a Western Digital connected to my router at 192.168.1.65 statically.

How can I automatically connect at login and rsync? 
At the moment I am using this command that doesn't work.

`rsync -Paz /home/chris/ 192.168.1.65:LinuxHome/`

but I get this

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.65 port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]`

This screenshot of the Western Digital MyBookWorld control panel might help

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2423935/wd.png

EDIT: I updated the command to `rsync -Paz -e ssh /home/chris/ 192.168.1.65:LinuxHome/` as suggested and it works (I also enabled ssh from the control panel) but I would like to connect-rsync automatically (either by a cron job or during login no matter to me)

Comment: Your command is not complete, try something like this: `rsync -Paz -e ssh /home/chris/ root@192.168.1.65:/LinuxHome/` Does the Router support rsync?

Comment: yes it supports ssh. That is why I gave this screenshot. It has some settings in it. I enabled SSH and now it works. Can I do this automatically without giving the password each time?

Comment: That was not the question. The question ist, does ist support rsync?

Comment: Try to set a authorized key to connect via ssh without a password. Here is some information about it: http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html

Comment: Thank you. I have created public and private keys. However there is a control panel (see my screenshot) in the web interface of the Western Digital. Can/should I use this and copy-paste anything? Would that make it easier for me to rsync without giving password?

Comment: I don't know your WD Box, but try to copy your public key in the "Key"-Field. Don't change anything, just copy it like it is. When it works you should connect with your Key and you won't be asked for a password while connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is not complete, try something like this:

`rsync -Paz -e ssh /home/chris/ root@192.168.1.65:/LinuxHome/`

To connect to your Box without giving a Password create an authorized_key. You can find a Howto hiere: http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html

Copy your public key in the "Key"-Field of you WC configuration. Don't change anything, just copy it like it is. When it works you should connect with your Key and you won't be asked for a password while connecting.